# Writing a formula into a cell include string variable

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to write a formula programatically related to excel date function.My problem is, I couldn't concatenate "=" and string variable in formula bar.

```
string frm = (yy + "- 1;" + mm + "- 0;" + dd + "- 0)").ToString();
selection.FormulaR1C1= "="+ frm;
```

If I use another code below  instead of frm it works, for example:

```
selection.FormulaR1C1= "="+ "formula";
```

Comment: Well that formula makes no sense. For a start it ends with a `)` but doesn't have a corresponding `(`. Take a look at the content of the `frm` variable.

Comment: yy    = "DATE(YEAR(DATEVALUE(" + trh + "))";
  mm = "MONTH(DATEVALUE(" + trh + "))";
  dd =   "DAY(DATEVALUE(" + trh + "))"; I think problem "trh" variable, trh is string of date and  ı use builder to add ' " ' beginnig and ending of string.At the end of the code ı get correct formula but  ı couldnt insert it formula bar

Comment: Solved: Problem was using ";" instead of ","